# Get length of decimal digit function

Tags: functions

I expect I can get length of decimal digit from function with given number input.

For example:

- $f(9)=1$
- $f(95)=2$
- $f(529)=3$

And so on...

What is the general form of $f(x)$?

Comment: Now prove why `floor(log(x))+1` is equivalent with `floor(log(x)+1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for $$f(x)=\lfloor\log_{10}x\rfloor+1$$

Comment: Yes, `f(x)=floor(log(x)) + 1` is already simplified version from your answer.

Comment: Yes of course, assuming $log$ means base 10. I prefer to emphasize the base.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I would prefer you not edit a matter of preference. It is standard to write ratios of the natural logarithm rather than writing a logarithm with a base. I have whole complex and real variables books that do this throughout.

Comment: If you try implementing this in any programming language, you will run into problems due to rounding errors - don’t be surprised if n=10^9 gives a result of 8. The result is undefined instead of 1 for x = 0.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Any number that fits into memory will process through a logarithm and have a perfectly accurate whole part within that same buffer size.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a positive integer $N$ represented in basis $B$, then the number of digits needed is exactly$\def\len{\operatorname{len}}$

$$\len_B(N)=1+\lfloor\log_B N\rfloor$$

where $\lfloor\,\cdot\,\rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

Comment: How to include `0` in function parameter so the function will return 1 digit? We know $log(0)$ is undefined in any base.

Comment: @Muhammad Ikhwan Perwira: Just special-case it: If $N=0$ then $len = 1$ else...